# resource_owner in Authorization API > create-token

Tags: sonos

When creating a token, I was anticipating it returning resource_owner, but I'm not seeing that. Any guidance on how I can get the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning of resource_owner is not implemented. We'll get the docs updated.

Comment: Thanks! Any advice on how to relate households to users/resource_owners today? At the moment, I've assumed the user = a household. I believe this works today as I've only seen one account per household and enables me to save user level preferences.

Comment: I think the most straightforward way would be to assign discovered households to whatever concept of user your system has.

Comment: Got ya.In my case, I've tried to 'delegate' the notion of user to Sonos. So, instead of the user needing to create an account on my side before linking, the account setup process is linking with Sonos, but I do understand why this wouldn't be a priority use case.